# CGAN - Odd Distribution gap, failure of convergence?

Tags: deep-learning, training, generative-models

I am trying to train on some 1 dimensional data (675 samples, its very expensive to get more) and trying to match the distribution seen here:
[image]

There are labels from 1-3 as to associated with the noise. After 2000, epochs, I generate 675 samples and the distribution doesn't look too swell. In addition, there is a odd spacing at $x = 1$ between [0.3, 0.5] as seen here:

[image]

Here are the losses:

[image]
[image]

Architecture (Top is discm, Bottom is Gen):
[image]

Any ideas :/ ?